# Updating job by mapping PubsubIO.Read to PubsubIO.Read/PubsubUnboundedSource gives 'Coder or type for step has changed' compatibility check failure?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm updating a currently running google cloud dataflow job from the v1.8 Java Dataflow SDK to v2.4 Java Dataflow SDK and as part of that process as per the release notes for the 1.x -> 2.x move (https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/release-notes/release-notes-java-2#changed_pubsubio_api) I'm changing the function PubsubIO.Read as used below:

```
 PCollection<String> streamData =
      pipeline
        .apply(PubsubIO.Read
                .timestampLabel(PUBSUB_TIMESTAMP_LABEL_KEY)
                .topic(options.getPubsubTopic()));
```

to instead be PubsubIO.readStrings() as below:

```
PCollection<String> streamData =
      pipeline
        .apply(PubsubIO.readStrings()
                .withTimestampAttribute(PUBSUB_TIMESTAMP_LABEL_KEY)
                .fromTopic(options.getPubsubTopic()));
```

Which then leads me to need to use the transform mapping command line argument like so

```
'--transformNameMapping={\"PubsubIO.Read\": \"PubsubIO.Read/PubsubUnboundedSource\"}'
```

But I get a compatabiltiy check failure:

> Workflow failed. Causes: The new job is not compatible with
>   2016-12-13_15_23_40-..... The original job has not been aborted., The
>   Coder or type for step PubsubIO.Read/PubsubUnboundedSource has
>   changed.

This confuses me a bit as it seems like the old code was working with strings and the new code is still using strings, can anyone help me understand what this error message is telling me? Is there perhaps a way for me to add a logging statement that will tell me what Coder I am using so that I can run my tests with my old code and new code and see what the difference is?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that you are trying to update an existing job. As the 2.x release introduced breaking changes, streaming jobs cannot be updated. There is a warning for users upgrading from 1.x at the top of that [documentation page](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/release-notes/release-notes-java-2) that reads:

> - Update Incompatibility: The Dataflow SDK 2.x for Java is update-incompatible with Dataflow 1.x. Streaming jobs using a Dataflow
>     1.x SDK cannot be updated to use a Dataflow 2.x SDK. Dataflow 2.x pipelines may only be updated across versions starting with SDK
>     version 2.0.0.

Regarding the Coder changes there is some explanation on [BEAM-1415](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-1415):

> There's no longer a way to read/write a generic type T. Instead,
>   there's `PubsubIO. {read,write} {Strings,Protos,PubsubMessages}`.
>   Strings and protos are a very common case so they have shorthands. For
>   everything else, use `PubsubMessage` and parse it yourself. In case of
>   read, you can read them with or without attributes. This gets rid of
>   the ugly use of Coder for decoding a message's payload (forbidden by
>   the style guide), and since PubsubMessage is easily encodable, again
>   the style guide also dictates to use that explicitly as the
>   input/return type of the transforms

In your tests you can use `CoderRegistry.getCoder()` as in [here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/test/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/coders/CoderRegistryTest.java#L78).