# Google Cloud Dataflow update pipeline

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to update an existing pipeline based on this manual(https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/updating-a-pipeline). The first update goes through without any issues, the second one, however, always fails. There is no difference in these two updates   - I am just changing a parameter in the deploy command (the `pii_fields` parameter).

The pipeline code is here https://pastebin.com/cRTjhNkg, the command I use for deploying looks like this:

```
python dev_radim_dataflow_gcs_direct_clean.py ^
 --project=<PROJECT_ID> ^
 --region="europe-west3" ^
 --input_subscription=projects/<PROJECT_ID>/subscriptions/dev-radim-dataflow-local ^
 --output_path_gcs=gs://dev_radim/dataflow_dest_local/GCS ^
 --output_table_bq=<PROJECT_ID>:dev_radim.dataflow_test_b ^
 --output_table_bq_schema=species:STRING,name:STRING,age:STRING,colour:STRING,publish_time:TIMESTAMP ^
 --rule_key=species ^
 --rule_value="guinea pig" ^
 --runner=DataflowRunner ^
 --window_size=1 ^
 --pii_fields=name
 --temp_location=gs://dev_radim/dataflow_temp_local/
```

The update command looks like this:

```
python dev_radim_dataflow_gcs_direct_clean.py ^
  --project=<PROJECT_ID> ^
  --update ^
  --job_name="<JOB NAME>" ^
  --region="europe-west3" ^
  --input_subscription=projects/<PROJECT_ID>/subscriptions/dev-radim-dataflow-local ^
  --output_path_gcs=gs://dev_radim/dataflow_dest_local/GCS ^
  --output_table_bq=<PROJECT_ID>:dev_radim.dataflow_test_b ^
  --output_table_bq_schema=species:STRING,name:STRING,age:STRING,colour:STRING,publish_time:TIMESTAMP ^
  --rule_key=species ^
  --rule_value="guinea pig" ^
  --runner=DataflowRunner ^
  --window_size=1 ^
  --pii_fields=name,age,colour ^
  --temp_location=gs://dev_radim/dataflow_temp/
```

When I run it for the second time, I am getting back `INFO:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.dataflow_runner:2021-03-04T12:42:04.147Z: JOB_MESSAGE_ERROR: Workflow failed. Causes: The new job is not compatible with <JOB_ID>. The original job has not been aborted.`

Do you have any idea why would the update be successful for the first time, but fail for the second time? And additionally, is there a way how to check what specific part is not compatible?

EDIT: I believe there is some optimization happening after the first update ([fusing steps](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/deploying-a-pipeline#fusion-optimization)) which causes the second update to fail.

Comment: have you tried surrounding the value passed with quotes ? 
`--pii_fields="name,age,colour" ^`

Comment: yes, I did. Unfortunately it didn't help.

Comment: Can you clarify why you're updating the job twice? Additionally there is a section in the manual about viewing [the error from a failed update attempt](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/updating-a-pipeline#CCheck). Is that the error you listed in the question? If not, maybe it could provide a more specific error message.

Comment: I am mimicking a situation where we'll want to update a running job every now and then. The error I am getting is the one with `JOB_MESSAGE_ERROR: Workflow failed`. The traceback that is shown looks like this: https://pastebin.com/zdJQFRYj

Comment: That error is coming from your client-side code, not your cloud job. It just indicates that something went wrong with the job, but not what. See if you can find the job in the Cloud UI and search the logs with Logs Explorer, you might be able to find more descriptive error messages that way.

Comment: the logs explorer doesn't say anything particularly helpful, it just says the job is not compatible and the workflow failed because of that. However, it didn't help me understand what part is not compatible.

Comment: In that case I don't have any other ideas except to keep trying to find where the error is logged (there should be an error similar to [the one in this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49863753/updating-job-by-mapping-pubsubio-read-to-pubsubio-read-pubsubunboundedsource-giv)). I've looked through your code and everything looks like it should work, so I don't know what the problem might be.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the time you spent on this. I'll continue the investigation and should I find anything, I'll update the question/post an answer.

Comment: another option would be to drain the job and launch it again, if the pipeline steps change too much you'll end up that way